# How to open ppt file in microsoft power point outside the cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm developing a cocoa application. I have a .ppt file in my resources. I have to open the ppt file in microsoft power point, when we tap a button within my application.

is it possible in cocoa using objective c?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible see this tutorial buddy

http://andycodes.tumblr.com/post/738375724/ios4-sdk-opening-pdfs-in-ibooks

Similarly you will have to do this for MS-Office.

Also See this apple documentation

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/QuickLook/Reference/QuickLookFrameworkReference_iPhoneOS/_index.html

UIDocumentInteractionController is the thing you need to use.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually we are developing app for mac. for mac QLPreview is available, when we open the PPT in the QLPreview, its first display like preview with an option "open with MS-Office" if MS-Office is installed in your system. When we tap over ms-office, it opens the ppt in MS-Office. But we have to directly open the ppt in MS-Office when we tap any of our custom button. No preview ia allowed as per requirement. is it something that is possible?

Comment: Yes I think it's possible. You can send PPT to MS-Office. There should be something in the docs. Please do some research on this.

Comment: or by executing the 'open' command with NSTask, it will be just like clicking it... and you can capture the stdout and stderr if you like...